# Boost not activating in Sitecore Solr query

Tags: solr, content-search

I've got some code that's generating a predicate for Solr search as follows:

```
foreach (string query in querySplit) {
  contentPredicate = contentPredicate.Or(item => item.DocumentTitle.Matches(query)).Boost(10.0f);
  contentPredicate = contentPredicate.Or(item => item.Body.Matches(query).Boost(5.0f));
}
```

When I look at the query that results from this in the log, I see the following:

```
70460 10:47:13 INFO  Solr Query - ?q=((((alltemplates_sm:(72220db715134422bcd8e74fdbb0a900) AND (-_name:("__Standard Values")  *:*)) AND (-_name:($name)  *:*)) AND (document_title_t:/advisory/ OR (body_t:/advisory/)^5))&start=0&rows=10&fq=_indexname:(sitecore_master_index)
```

So I see the boost on the Body field, but not on the DocumentTitle field. I've tried a lower boost value on DocumentTitle, but it's not picking it up in any circumstance. DocumentTitle is a single-line text field, and Body is a rich text field. These are using the out-of-box definitions for the fields, no computed fields. Why would the boost not be applied to certain fields?

Comment: It looks like your parenthesis need to be fixed. Try `contentPredicate = contentPredicate.Or(item => item.DocumentTitle.Matches(query).Boost(10.0f))`.

Comment: @AlessandroFaniuolo That looks like it was the answer. Can you provide that as the answer (instead of a comment) so I can credit you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your parenthesis need to be fixed.

Try `contentPredicate = contentPredicate.Or(item => item.DocumentTitle.Matches(query).Boost(10.0f))` instead.